# Libstreaming - use VLC as a RTSP client

Tags: java, android, rtsp, rtsp-client, libstreaming

I'm trying to use VLC as a RTSP client. The RTSP server is based on the `libstreaming` library. I'm using the code provided by the [1rst example](https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming-examples/blob/master/example1/src/net/majorkernelpanic/example1/MainActivity.java):

```
        // Sets the port of the RTSP server to 1234
        Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
        editor.putString(RtspServer.KEY_PORT, String.valueOf(1234));
        editor.commit();

        // Configures the SessionBuilder
        SessionBuilder.getInstance()
        .setSurfaceView(mSurfaceView)
        .setPreviewOrientation(90)
        .setContext(getApplicationContext())
        .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_NONE)
        .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264);

        // Starts the RTSP server
        this.startService(new Intent(this,RtspServer.class));
```

The android app starts; I try to access the stream using VLC (`open a stream`) and this URL:

```
rtsp://192.168.43.250:1234
```

The device is connected to the same network (I can ping it), but nothing happens in the android App and VLC displays a "connection failed" window.

Any idea where the problem is? Maybe a bad URL, but I can't found any detailled example of this situation.

Comment: could you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4):

It throws null pointer, check the logcat.

you have to provide the url as rtsp://ip:1234?h264=200-20-320-240

200 - buf
20 - fps
320 - resolution w
240 - resolution h

Comment: I'm using `rtsp://172.xx.xx.67:1777?h264=500000-15-640-480`: log on android stream server: OPTIONS 200 -> DESCRIBE 200 -> SETUP 200 -> PLAY 200 -> TEARDOWN 200 -> Error parsing CSeq (IllegalStateException: No successful match so far) - no method in the request

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems. Here is my solution.

1. Make sure you have imported the library as an imported module through android studio
2. Give your manifest the permission to use the resources needed
3. Use this code for you MainActivity:

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, RtspServer.CallbackListener, Session.Callback{

       private final static String TAG = "MainActivity";

       private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
       private  Session mSession;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

           getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


           setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);




           // Sets the port of the RTSP server to 1234
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
           editor.putString(  RtspServer.KEY_PORT, String.valueOf(1234));
           editor.commit();



           // Configures the SessionBuilder
          mSession =  SessionBuilder.getInstance()
               .setCallback(this)
               .setSurfaceView((net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView) mSurfaceView)
               .setPreviewOrientation(90)
               .setContext(getApplicationContext())
               .setAudioEncoder(SessionBuilder.AUDIO_AAC)
               .setAudioQuality(new AudioQuality(8000, 16000))
               .setVideoEncoder(SessionBuilder.VIDEO_H264)
               //.setVideoQuality(new VideoQuality(320,240,20,500000))
               .build();

           mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);

           ((net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView) mSurfaceView).setAspectRatioMode(net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.gl.SurfaceView.ASPECT_RATIO_PREVIEW);
           String ip, port, path;

           // Starts the RTSP server
           this.startService(new Intent(this,RtspServer.class));

           Log.d("test", "1");



           mSession.startPreview(); //camera preview on phone surface
           mSession.start();

       }

       @Override
       public void onResume()
       {
           super.onResume();
           mSession.stopPreview();
       }

       @Override
       public void onDestroy()
       {
           super.onDestroy();
           mSession.release();
           mSurfaceView.getHolder().removeCallback(this);
       }

       //region   ----------------------------------implement methods required
       @Override
       public void onError(RtspServer server, Exception e, int error) {
           Log.e("Server", e.toString());
       }

       @Override
       public void onMessage(RtspServer server, int message) {
           Log.e("Server", "unkown message");
       }

       @Override
       public void onBitrateUpdate(long bitrate) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onSessionError(int reason, int streamType, Exception e) {

       }

       @Override
       public void onPreviewStarted() {

       }

       @Override
       public void onSessionConfigured() {

       }

       @Override
       public void onSessionStarted() {

       }

       @Override
       public void onSessionStopped() {

       }

       @Override
       public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

       }

       @Override
       public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

       }

       @Override
       public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

       }

       //endregion
   }
   ```
4. using VLC player open the open network stream and type

rtsp://the ip of android device:1234 <--this port is hard coded so don't change

Answer (score 0):

When I worked with libstreaming & VLC I spent a lot of time with the same problem. The solution for me was to use other VLC version. For example, it worked for me on vlc ver. 1.0.5, but many other versions didn't play the stream.

Answer (score 0):

))) the first example is a server (for the author of the library, the server is someone who accepts the stream and does not give)
you need to use 2 or 3 example ...
2 example is good because you only need a VLK player ...

1. find out your Ip (cmd-> ipconfig) (it's important to understand that the device must have an external ip address or is in the same network)

   2. Specify the received ip address of the PC in mEditText (mSession.setDestination ();)
   3. After launching the application, press the start button. The studio in the logs will return the contents to create the sdp format file (TAG, mSession.getSessionDescription ());
   4. create a falix for example 1.sdp edit it by specifying the contents of getSessionDescription (remove extra spaces)
      huge minutes then that we need to specify the ip of the one we want to send the stream to ...

      **now the main thing! in any of the examples it does not turn out to simply enter rtsp: //192.168.43.250: 1234 and get the video !!! - 0)))))))**

      In the Session class, you'll find mOrigin = "127.0.0.1"; ok SessionBuilder .... .setOrigin ("192.xxx.xxx.xx")

      Further your logic may suggest that you only need to find the port and maybe you will find SessionBuilder Session build () video.setDestinationPorts (5006);
       but this is not the port)))

      in this library there is no rtsp server implementation (I'm writing a server since it means that we want to raise the server for ip cam on the device)
       
       you can find the hint in the RtspClient class (pay attention to the author of the library, this is the one who gives it) and there the author writes to us
       
       * RFC 2326.
       * A basic and asynchronous RTSP client.
       RTSP client compatible with Wowza.
       * It implements Digest Access Authentication according to RFC 2069.